# Flutter Error running pod install after adding firebase packages to dependencies

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, cocoapods

Whenever I try to run pod install on my project after adding firebase to my dependencides I get this error message

Dependencies:
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
firebase_core: ^2.14.0
firebase_auth: ^4.6.3
cloud_firestore: ^4.7.1
flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.3

> CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/9.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Timeout was reached
>
> ```
> /Users/salmon/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:483:in `rescue in concurrent_requests_catching_errors'
> /Users/salmon/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:478:in `concurrent_requests_catching_errors'
> /Users/salmon/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-.
> ```
>
> .
> .
> .
> /Users/salmon/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>' /Users/salmon/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin/pod:25:in` load'
> /Users/salmon/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin/pod:25:in `'
>
> Error running pod install
> Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.

I have tried to uninstall & install the cocoapods, ruby and nothing worked for me
I also tried sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi and i get "Bad CPU type in executable"